# How to retrieve variable from multi-level array - Vue.js

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I'm just doing a practice project in Vue.js, I'm going to loop through a team page from the NHL and output the name of each player.

I've got an API endpoint here;
https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/21?expand=team.roster

I'm trying to traverse through the levels but am getting "lost" at the roster. I can output the whole roster but can't seem to drill any further down than that.

I'm storing the contents of the entire JSON response in a variable called "hockeyData".

This is what I'm using to output the roster (this works)

```
{{ hockeyData[0].roster }}
```

Now when I try to get the player names, I'm doing this and it doesn't work

```
{{ hockeyData[0].roster.roster[0].person.fullName }}
```

I'm sure it's something simple but try as I might I'm just not getting the name to output.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the error that u r getting?

Comment: I get a console error of "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roster')"

Comment: Just add a logical statement `this.hockeyData && this.hockeyData[0].roster.roster[0].person.fullName` or `this.hockeyData[0]?.roster.roster[0].person.fullName` to solve TypeError. This is because at the time the component is created, hockeyData may has no data (so it`s null or undefined in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working [example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/josfabre/pen/vYJvGrG) based on your data.

You haven't posted any code so I can't be sure, but your issue could be a timing issue. Make sure the values are available at the time of requesting from the template.

I have an `v-if` in my example around the data that checks if the data is available (for example purpose, I'm only checking if the roster is available, I should check for all children, but it's an example..).

```
    <div v-if="roster && roster.length">
        First: {{ roster[0].person.fullName }}
    </div>
```